# Empty string when trying to convert const char * to NSString

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have encountered a strange bug while trying to get a NSString from a const char *.

```
// in my obj c class
void myObjCMethod {
    const char* charString = myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr(); 
    printf("%s \n", charString); // prints the correct string

    // ...put a brakpoint here... 

    NSString * nsString1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:charString];
    NSLog(@"%@", nsString1); // prints nothing

    NSString * nsString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",charString];
    NSLog(@"%@", nsString2); // prints nothing either
}
```

The const char coming from my c method prints nicely to the console. But trying to convert to NSString results in an empty string.
Now the weirdest thing is, that when I try to debug the code and set a breakpoint (as indicated above), my NSString suddenly *becomes* valid!

So what -- my mesurement changes the result? Sounds familiar from physics class long ago, but I doubt there is quantum mechanics involved here.

Note:

I have omitted the implementation of `myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr()` for now, as it would add another layer of complexity that is probably not related to the present problem (There are multiple c++ libraries involved, the string has been converted from char pointer to std::string and back).

I've been banging my head against this for two days now, any help is appreciated very much! Thanks

**EDIT:**

The string initially comes from the struct `SPODNode` from PowerVR's Insider SDK.
There we have:

```
struct SPODNode {
    PVRTchar8 *pszName;
    // ...
}
```

With:

```
typedef char PVRTchar8;
```

In my code I do:

```
std::string MyCppClass::pvrNodeName() {
    if (node && node->pszName) {
        string stdName(node->pszName);
        return stdName;
    }
    return string();
}
```

And finally in `myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr()`:

```
const char * myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr() {
    std::string stdString = myCppClassInstace->pvrNodeName()
    return stdString.c_str();
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I would suspect `myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr()`. Could you show it?

Comment: Not so easy, there's too much code involved. I will try to break it down and add it to my question. I was hoping the given example stands for itself.

Comment: I am interested in the way your `const char*` is returned. In particular, whether it is obtained from a local `std::string` object through a call to `data()` or `c_str()`.

Comment: Can you at least show the output of the "correct string"? Are there any non-ASCII characters involved? `stringWithUTF8String` fails if the string is not correct UTF-8.

Comment: The problem also appears with the string "foo"

Comment: The const char * is obtained by calling .c_str() on a std::string.

Comment: @de.: Is the `std::string` a local object?

Comment: @de. Is that string a local variable?

Comment: I have updated the question with more code examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The const char * is obtained by calling .c_str() on a std::string.

It is very likely that your program has **Undefined Behavior**, because you are returning a pointer to an array of character that gets deallocated when returning from function `myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr()`.

In fact, that `const char*` you return points to a character array that is encapsulated by a local `std::string` object; the destructor of the `std::string` object deallocates that array, and the destructor is invoked when the local object goes out of scope, i.e. when returning from the function.

Later attempts to dereference the pointer you receive result in Undefined Behavior, which means anything could happen. This includes your program seeming to run fine when being debugged, but not when running without the debugger attached.

You should have your function return (by value) an `std::string`, and then invoke `c_str()` on that returned value if you need to get the encapsulated C-string:

```
std::string charString = myCFunctionReturningConstCharPtr(); 
printf("%s \n", charString.c_str()); // prints the correct string
```

Comment: Please see the code in my updated question above. From my understanding that is what I do. I am converting my std string using c_str(). The result is a const and should thus still be valid when I return it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @de.: No, it is not valid. As I write in my answer, that character array is owned by the local `std::string` object, and when this goes out of scope, the character array is deleted. Return a `std::string` instead of a `const char*`, as I suggested.

Comment: Ok, I see. But I have to convert to c because my API is c only, no c++.

Comment: @de. In that case you can allocate a new character array and copy the one returned by `c_str()` into it. In this case, the client will have the responsibility of doing `delete[]` on it. Alternatively, you could let the client pass a buffer to your function, so the function itself only has to copy the result of `c_str()` into it without allocating it. This solution is better IMO, as the client has the choice of how to allocate the buffer (whether on the stack or on the heap)

Comment: Thanks Andy, I will follow your second suggestion. That will hopefully solve my problem. I'll get back once I've got it running.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. You literally saved my day here. Thanks a lot!